# How to write the output of a command twice into a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I run some command that generates ip address as output. But I am developing a workflow where I need the ip address to be written twice. Below is the sample command and its output.

```
$ some command >> out.txt

$ cat out.txt
10.241.1.85
hdfs://10.241.1.236/
hdfs://10.241.1.237/
```

What i want is to duplicate the output and it should look like this.

```
10.241.1.85
hdfs://10.241.1.236/
hdfs://10.241.1.237/
10.241.1.85
hdfs://10.241.1.236/
hdfs://10.241.1.237/
```

Any help please?

Comment: Try `var=$(some cmd); echo -e "$var\n$var"`.

Comment: I was just about to post that,, however that said I would suggest you tell more about the workflow that needs the duplicate data in the file.. I would hazard to say that it could be enhance to work off a single instance of the data..

Comment: the some cmd is a huge one which cannot be assigned to a variable. Can u tell me a way that can duplicate the content of a file without changing the file name?

Comment: you could just cat the file file twice and pipe to stdin for the command ;)

Comment: @Rob how can i do that?

Comment: cat filename filename | <command> :) so in your case cat out.txt out.txt | <big command>

Comment: Ok..Lets forget about the big command. Imagine that I have a file and I want its content to be duplicated into the same file. How to achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111894/discussion-between-alex-raj-kaliamoorthy-and-rob).

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @ott in a comment seems fine:

```
 var=$(some cmd); echo -e "$var\n$var".
```

This is not assigning the command o a varable but it is assigning the output of the command to a variable.

When you do not want this, you can use `tee` (perhaps this will give some ordering problems) or duplicate it differently:

```
some_command > out.txt.tmp
cat out.txt.tmp out.txt.tmp > out.txt
rm out.txt.tmp
```

This way you first get the lines of the copy after al the lines of first entries. When you want to double the output directly, you can use

```
some_command | sed 'p' > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some command | tee -a out.txt out.txt
```

Or

```
some command | tee -a out.txt >> out.txt
```

Or

```
some command | tee -a out.txt out.txt >/dev/null
```

1. Run command
2. Pipe to tee
3. Enable append mode
4. Append to same file twice

Answer (score 0):

Generate the output to some temporary, then duplicate the temporary to destination and remove temporary :

```
some command > /tmp/out.txt; cat /tmp/out.txt /tmp/out.txt > out.txt; rm /tmp/out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more options you could play around with. Seeing as the output is too large to store in a variable, I'd probably go with `tee`, a temp file, and `gzip` if the disk write speed is a bottleneck.

```
someCommand > tmp.txt && cat tmp.txt tmp.txt > out.txt && rm tmp.txt
```

Now, if the disk read/write speed is a bottleneck, you can tee the output of `someCommand` and redirect one of the pipelines through gzip initially.

```
someCommand | tee >(gzip > tmp.gz) > out.txt && gunzip -c tmp.gz >> out.txt && rm tmp.gz
```

Additionally, if you don't need random access abilities for out.txt and plan on processing it through some other pipeline, you could always keep it stored gzipped until you need it.

```
someCommand | gzip > tmp.gz && cat tmp.gz tmp.gz > out.txt.gz && rm tmp.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
(someCommand | tee tmp.txt; cat tmp.txt) > out.txt; rm tmp.txt
```

Not sure there's a way to safely do this without resorting to a temporary file. You could capture it to a variable, as some have suggested, but you have to be careful about quoting then to make sure whitespace doesn't get mangled, and you also might run into problems if the output is particularly large.